# Cannot load JDBC driver class 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver' when compiling Grails project

Tags: grails, jdbc, compilation, jtds

This is my first post so be gentle!  :)

I've set up a grails project (fairly new at grails too) and am attempting to connect it to a SQL 2008 database, I've added the jtds-1.3.0.jar to the lib folder and to my build path, and then I've altered my DataSource.groovy file to read as follows: -

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"
    }

hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}


// environment specific settings
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
        url= "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://TestServer:1433;databaseName=TestTable"
            username = "test"
            password = "test"
        // logSql=true
        }
    }
```

Trouble is when I try to compile I get a massive error which reads as follows, what am I missing?  I've googled about but can't find an obvious solution... :S

```
| Error 2013-03-08 12:44:33,451 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver'
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have had similar problems in the past.

I've changed the version of JTDS to 1.2.6 and all works fine.

By the way - you don't need to add the jar manually. You just have to add the following to your `BuildConfig.groovy` (in the dependencies section):

```
runtime 'net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.2.6'
```

Comment: +1 The thing to note is that jTDS 1.3.0 requires Java 7, it will not load if you're using Java 6.

Comment: +1 Now compiles fine, and using the runtime comment also works a treat!  Thanks! :)

Comment: jTDS v1.3.1 kept wanting to load a message_en_US.properties file, which is not included within the jar file.  Only message.properties is.  As soon as I reverted back to 1.2.6, this issue disappeared.

Comment: but I am still unable to deploy the war file on tomcat. same error