# Could not find artifact net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:zip:1.2.6 in grailsCentral

Tags: sql-server-2008, maven, grails, jdbc

I am basing on [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294645/cannot-load-jdbc-driver-class-net-sourceforge-jtds-jdbc-driver-when-compiling)  to connect to SQL Server database .

driverClassName = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"
url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://myurl:1433/mydb"

I add also dependencies on buildConfig.groovy

```
runtime 'net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.2.6'
```

Unfortunately ,Console displays this error:

```
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:zip:1.2.6 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Could not find artifact net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:zip:1.2.6 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)
| Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.
```

Comment: Post your BuildConfig.groovy ... it may be that you don't have any maven repositories enabled either.

Comment: If you want that this question is not closed, you still need to add the missing information to the question. Questions must be self-contained, so it is not enough that one can deduce what was wrong from the answer(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dependencies {
   runtime 'net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.2.6'
}
```

and not

```
plugins{

  runtime 'net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.2.6'
}
```